# coffeescript compile to javascript adjust indentation size

Tags: javascript, compilation, coffeescript, sublimetext3

I'm using sublime text to write coffeescript, when I compile the coffeescript source file to javascript using command:

```
coffee -c myCoffee.coffee
```

I get the myCoffee.js I wanted but with tab size being 2 spaces, I want the tab size of the compiled javascript file to be 4 spaces, is there anyway to achieve that?

Comment: I only use vertical tabs, best way to go. -> http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/11?m=26216651#26216651

Comment: ? I'm not following? what do you mean vertical tabs? Are we referring the same thing? In my case tab means indentation

Comment: Ignore @Jesse, they're just trying to be clever and failing. As far as the indentation goes, why does it matter? The JavaScript output isn't really meant to be read by humans, whatever indentation is there is probably just a debugging aid.

Comment: @muistooshort - :(. Here is what you are looking for I think (since you mentioned using Sublime) http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/indentation

Comment: Yeah, debug is exactly what I'm trying to do here, since I'm a newcomer to coffeescript, I need to make sure the coffeescript code I wrote compiles to the right javascript code I want, and reading the tight 2-space indentation javascript code is killing my eyes so...

Comment: @Jesse: I don't think that's it, dulan is writing CoffeeScript in Sublime and then converting that CoffeeScript to JavaScript, the generated JavaScript comes out with 2 spaces for indentation and I don't see any [options](http://coffeescript.org/#usage) for adjusting that.

Comment: After opening the javascript file in Sublime Text, I tried to change the tab size to 4 and then reindent the whole file, Sublime's reindent doesn't do its job well.... Finally I managed to work it out by using Webstorm to open the js file and auto-indent the whole file to make it indent with 4 spaces. This is   a workaround for me, so I'm guessing there's no way to do it completely automatically... not that I'm aware of

Comment: If you are manually doing it, can I suggest http://jsbeautifier.org/ ... I tried looking around dude, best I came up with was https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/indentation.html

Comment: @Jesse Did try to change the tab size settings of sublime as well, turns out when it comes to auto-indentation, Webstorm does quite a better job than Sublime, but thanks guys :)

Comment: If you look for a lighter alternative to Webstorm for auto-indent, Visual Studio Code is quite good at formatting JS (there is shortcut by default: alt+shift+f) and support CoffeeScript syntax highlighting out of the box.